# error: ‘length’ was not declared in this scope c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, scope

I am beginner c++ programmer, It's my first program even (For those who are very keen to give negatives). I had written the same code in c but now trying to do in c++.
Where I get the following error.

`error: ‘length’ was not declared in this scope`

My code is as below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <assert.h>
using namespace std;


 class Huffman
 {
    public:

    int data_size, length; //THis length variable is not accessible in main function below in main function.
     Huffman(char *filename);
   ~Huffman();

    struct Huffman1
    {
    int value;
    unsigned char sym;                 /* symbol */
    struct Huffman1 *left,*right;    /* left and right subtrees */
    };   typedef struct Huffman1 Node;

 };

 Huffman::Huffman(char * file_name)
 {

 //I will do something here soon

 }
  Huffman::~Huffman()
 {

 }


 int main(int argc, char * * argv)
 {
      length=10; //Not accessible here.
     if (argc < 2)
    {
        cout<<"Ohh.. Sorry , you forgot to provide the Input File please" <<endl;
        return(0);
    }
     Huffman Object1(argv[1]);

     return(0);


}
```

I am not sure that it's c++ programming error because it may be because i am compiling it `g++ Filename.c -o filename`. Could someone please correct if it's a programming error or it's due to the way i compile ?
thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what it is you're trying to do. You are trying to change something's length to 10 -- but what is the something? At that point in your code, there doesn't exist anything that has a `length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a compile error and your code is responsible. You defined `length` inside your `Huffman` class. It's a member of that class, not a global variable.

Imagine your class as a C Struct. You'd need to create a struct first in order to access the variable. Same thing applies to C++ classes.

Try `Object1.length = 10;` **after** you create the instance of your class.

**EDIT**

For your purposes, use C++ classes as you would use C structs. That will do the trick.

I would actually put the `Node` struct declaration outside of the `Huffman` class. I think it's easier to understand. Also, using a typedef to a struct is not really that useful in C++ for these cases, the name of the struct is usable by just declaring the struct.

The pointers do not allocate memory for the struct themselves. Only after you allocate memory they will be usable, and even then they're members of `Object1`, so you need that too.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <assert.h>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int value;
    unsigned char sym;                 /* symbol */
};

 class Huffman
 {
    public:

    int data_size, length; //THis length variable is not accessible in main function below in main function.
     Huffman(char *filename);
   ~Huffman();

    Node *left,*right;    /* left and right subtrees */

 };

 Huffman::Huffman(char * file_name)
 {

 //I will do something here soon

 }
  Huffman::~Huffman()
 {

 }


 int main(int argc, char * * argv)
 {
      length=10; //Not accessible here.
     if (argc < 2)
    {
        cout<<"Ohh.. Sorry , you forgot to provide the Input File please" <<endl;
        return(0);
    }
     Huffman Object1(argv[1]);

     Object1.left  = new Node;
     Object1.right = new Node;

     //Do your stuff here...
     Object1.left->sym;

     return(0);


}
```

This should get you started, it is by no means a perfect implementation. It's not even very C++ oriented, but I already went ahead of myself with the answer. This is a topic for a very different question, which you're welcome to ask in SO, but try not to make questions inside questions.

Good luck!

Comment: @MooingDuck OP stated he created the same program in C.

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks for beautiful answer. I have one more doubt. I have to do  "Node *tree; tree->sym;" in main function(Please see the Struct in my class Huffman in my code again).How to make   Node *tree; tree->sym; make work inside main() scope ? Thanks again..

Comment: @user3206225 You're welcome =)
The Node type is defined inside your class. Something like Node *tree; is not possible with your current structure. Something like Object1.Node *tree; might do the trick. What is it that you're trying to do exactly?

Comment: I am developing huffman tree in c++. I have already developed in c but now i have to do it in c++. Could you please help in designing the structure (I have to read frequency from a file"Input.txt" as sole argument). I just need help in desiging body after i can do it myself. You can answer me here if you want. I will mark it accepted anwer. Thank you so much.

Comment: thanks for the answer, Here is my new question (as you suggested me to do). Could you please help me there.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715626/how-to-create-huffman-tree-in-c

Answer (score 4):

`length` is a member of the class, so it does not exist outside the class.

You can access `lenth` after creating an object of class `Huffman` as follows

```
Huffman Object(argv[1]);
Object.length = 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

**length** belongs to **Huffman** class. So you should use it for Object1 after it's definition:

```
Huffman Object1(argv[1]);

Object1.length = 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

You know, `public:` doesn't mean that anything put inside under that branch in the class tree, will be accessible everywhere it just means that you access the instance variables of the class through "dot notation" like so `Object.length`.

However if you truly wanted length to be accessible everywhere, you should declare it as a global variable:

```
short int length;
class Huffman{
...
};
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`length` is part of your class, not main, thus the compiler is right.
Members belong to an object and are accessed liek this:

```
Huffman huffmannObj(...);
std::cout << huffmannObj.length << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

`length` is a publicly accessible member of your class, but you'll need an instance of that class first before you can do anything with the member

```
Huffman h(whatever_constructor_params);
h.length = 10;
```

...is ok